# How to get every possible combination of string from array/hash in ruby?

Tags: ruby, combinations, permutation

I'm junior backend trying ruby. I have these data:

```
people = ["Andy", "Budi", "Charles"]
vehicles = ["Bicycle", "Car", "Bajaj"]
destinations = ["USA", "Bali", "Paradise"]


string_format = %{person} ride %{vehicle} to %{destination}
```

How to get the all possible combination of the string using ruby?
Expected output total of 27 items (3 x 3 x 3):

```
1. Andy ride Bicycle to USA
2. Andy ride Bicycle to Bali
3. Andy ride Bicycle to Paradise
4. Andy ride Car to USA

...

27. Charles ride Bajaj to Paradise
```

the code should be extensible, because later we will add more array such as:

```
adjectives = ["happily", "sadly"]

string_format = %{destination} has been visited by %{person} using %{his_or_her} %{vehicle} %{adjectives}
```

Comment: I am confused. You are asking about Combinations and Permutations as if they were the same thing (which they are not), but your desired output looks more like the Cartesian Product. Can you give a clear specification as to how you arrive at the output from the input? It is very hard to create a general solution from only one single example.

Comment: @JörgWMittag sorry, I don't really know the right wording on the problem, I need to generate very possible combination ,given the array input

Comment: What do you mean by "every possible combination"? Your desired output does not look like combinations. Can you give a clear specification as to how you arrive at the output from the input? It is very hard to create a general solution from only one single example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#product`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Array.html#method-i-product) to return an array with all combinations:

```
people.product(vehicles, destinations)
# => [["Andy", "Bicycle", "USA"], ["Andy", "Bicycle", "Bali"], ["Andy", "Bicycle", "Paradise"], ["Andy", "Car", "USA"], ["Andy", "Car", "Bali"], ["Andy", "Car", "Paradise"], ["Andy", "Bajaj", "USA"], ["Andy", "Bajaj", "Bali"], ["Andy", "Bajaj", "Paradise"], ["Budi", "Bicycle", "USA"], ["Budi", "Bicycle", "Bali"], ["Budi", "Bicycle", "Paradise"], ["Budi", "Car", "USA"], ["Budi", "Car", "Bali"], ["Budi", "Car", "Paradise"],["Budi", "Bajaj", "USA"],["Budi", "Bajaj", "Bali"],["Budi", "Bajaj", "Paradise"],["Charles", "Bicycle", "USA"],["Charles", "Bicycle", "Bali"],["Charles", "Bicycle", "Paradise"],["Charles", "Car", "USA"],["Charles", "Car", "Bali"],["Charles", "Car", "Paradise"],["Charles", "Bajaj", "USA"],["Charles", "Bajaj", "Bali"],["Charles", "Bajaj", "Paradise"]]
```

Which can be used to output your list like this:

```
people.product(vehicles, destinations).each do |person, vehicle, destination|
  puts "#{person} ride #{vehicle} to #{destination}"
end
```